# SharePoint - programmatically update elements that stays in previous versions? Is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint, versioning

I have multiple lines field with these settings:

[image]

So I have some records "history" in 'MultipleLinesField':

[image]

Is it possible to get ListItem from versions collections and update this field? I understand that I can restore some version to actual, and then change field, but I want to keep order of these records from newest to last. Is it possible in OM?

I tried but no luck. I can get it, but can not change.

SPListItem itm = web.Lists["ListWithVersions"].GetItemById(1);

```
        string fieldName = itm.Fields["MultipleLinesField"].InternalName;

        for (int i = 0; i < itm.Versions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (itm.Versions[i][fieldName] != null)
            {
                Message("Version: " + i + Environment.NewLine + itm.Versions[i][fieldName]);

                // Error    Property or indexer 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemVersion.this[string]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
                itm.Versions[i][fieldName] = "asdfgh";

                // Error    Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemVersion' to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem'
                ((SPListItem)itm.Versions[i]).SystemUpdate();
            }
        }
```